# Extracting hyperlinks from a page using wget and grep

Tags: regex, bash, grep, wget, pcre

I'm trying to extract all hypelinks within a single page using wget and grep and I found this code using PCRE to get all the hyperlinks.

But I'm not really familiar with regex or html, so I really want to know if this is a sound way of going about it or if there is a better way.
I also have a question about it. Do you really need to escape the quotes? I tested it a few times but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

```
wget https://google.com -q -O - | grep -Po '(?<=href=\")[^\"]*'
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Well, it does seem to work.  What's the problem?

Comment: @Jack I'm just vaguely worried about whether or not this will work with all use cases. Since I really don't know much about HTML, I'm just hoping someone could confirm if this is properly done

Comment: No, it wont work in all cases and it's not properly done. Google xmlstarlet and xmllint to see some of the tools for parsing XML robustly (or tag this question with them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command will grab the contents of all href strings `href="..."` that exist entirely on one line.

You don't need to individually escape your doublequotes `\"` if the whole string is surrounded by `'single quotes'`. The point of quoting is to prevent characters from being interpreted by the shell. The only time you need to escape doublequotes is when you're allowing for expansions, e.g.:

```
foo=href
grep -Po "(?<=${foo}=\")[^\"]*"
```

This is exactly identical to

```
grep -Po '(?<=href=")[^"]*'
```

Which means

- Grep, using `P`CRE
- return `o`nly the match
- look for any string preceded by `(?<=...)` the literal string `href="`
- match anything that's not a doublequote `[^"]`
- zero or more times `*`

The use of `*` may return an empty string if you ever parse `<a href="">`. You could use `+` (one or more times) instead of `*` (zero or more times).